Prisma - Query list for partial matches
My prisma model have these 2 string list properties
  names     String[]
  phones    String[]  @unique

I want to query this table and along with many other search params,  I want to find all records where any name or any phone contains a given value.
This for instance work, but only for phones matching the query value exactly
  if (params.query) {
    whereCondition = {
      phones: {
        has: params.query,
      },
    };
  }

I think one can write raw sql, but would like to avoid that and do the above along with various other criteria building up a "where condition"

No need to break out raw SQL, this is a supported scenario..
Here's an example to match either partial email or partial phone number. I adapted it from "the official documentation" so definitely check it out. You didn't provide the full schema, so I'm making some assumptions here:
const phoneNumber = '123-456';

const users = await prisma.user.findMany({
  where: {
    // Match either email or phone number
    OR: [
      {
        email: {
          // Match emails ending with the value
          endsWith: 'prisma.io',
          // use case-insensitive search
          mode: 'insensitive',
        },
      },
      {
        phones: {
          // Match phone numbers that include the string
          contains: {
            phoneNumber,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
});


